# Android Algorithm Google Direction Check start point and destination point in the polyline

Tags: android, algorithm, google-maps, firebase

I have a project, it 's a carpooling app that means you can find people who can give you a lift if, in there plan road, they can pick you up and take you to where you want to go.

The problem is about algỏrithm to find a suitable trip match with my start place and destination place, that mean my start place location and destination place location have to be in their road and same direction.

I think about user google map direction to download overview_polyline then I can have a list of latlng to test, but then I have to save the list to firebase data and get them whatever I want to test, that requires a lot of data because latlng points of the road is too many and also too many posts about the trip have to be saved.

if you guys have a better idea for this situation or know some tool, algorithm, API which can solve this problem please show me your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should store the user's navigation route as a polyline(i.e. save it's geometry), maybe in PostGIS because you will have 100's and 1000's of routes to be saved, and then whenever any user queries to find any available car you apply intersection between the user's current location and the saved route in the PostGIS DB.

Hope it helped. :)